# Change height of element when content changes?

Tags: angularjs

In a AngularJS app, using ui-router, i want to change the height of an element (sidebar), when the content inside the sidebar gets updated.

Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: 'The content', is this an angular variable?

Comment: You should provide an example and/or code and explain what you are trying to accomplish in greater detail.